# Why Code igniter holds the output of views in a buffer

Tags: php, codeigniter, output-buffering

I have a very basic code below  i am new to code igniter so pardon if my question sound amateur

```
    public function view($num = 0) {

    echo "View was called<br>";

    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view('xyz');
    $this->load->view('footer');

    echo "View function ended";
    }
```

Ok so i want to know why code igniter doesn't output result the way it is return

The ouptut of the code  is as following

1. View was called
2. output of the result by calling random_func()
3. Renders view

What is expected from the output is as following

1. View was called
2. Renders view
3. output of the result by calling random_func()

Is there any code igniter specific behavior i am missing on?why code igniter holding the views  in buffer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow Codeigniters lifecycle in `/system/core/Codeigniter.php` you will see that the final output gets called near the very end of the file.

So views will always get output to the browser last, regardless of how they are called.

When a view is called, it gets stored in the buffer so it can be manipulated before it gets sent for final render.

Manipulating the buffer could be anything from storing one view in another, parsing/injecting variable data/tags etc.

### Codeingiter Lifecycle(in Order)

1. Defines some Global Constants(CI_VERSION, CI_CORE) version control
2. Loads the core/Common.php file which includes some GLOBAL helper
   functions
3. Checks which ENVIRONMENT the framework is running
   under(local/remote)
4. Sets a Custom Error handler for handling Errors/Exceptions
5. Loads the config file to check if there is a custom subclass prefix
   eg: (MY_)
6. Set a liberal script execution time limit
7. Loads the Benchmark class so anything under this line can be
   benchmarked!
8. Loads the hOOk class and checks if their are any 'pre_system' hooks
   defined in application/hooks
9. Loads the main config file and assigns everything inside the file to
   the config array
10. loads the UTF-8 and URI classes
11. Loads the router class and sets the default route in
    /application/config/routes.php => default_controller
12. loads the output class and checks if there is anything in the cache
    that can be output straightaway
13. loads security/Input/lang classes
14. Loads the Controller class(entry point) and sub classes that extend
    it in application/controllers
15. checks to see if a Controller method begins with and _ => this is
    private
16. Does some other security checks and looks for an index method in
    the controller and searches for requested controller
17. looks for a pre_controller Hook
18. Instantiates the requested controller from step 16
19. looks for a post_controller_construct Hook
20. looks for a controller _remap override function
21. looks for a post_controller Hook, this happens after the controller
    __construct method has been called
22. Outputs the final Render(buffer) to the browser
23. looks for a post_system Hook
24. Closes any DB Connections that are open
25. Back to step 1

As you can see now from the cycle, If you wanted to intercept it at any point, you would created a HOOK, and those hooks will get injected at the point the hooks are called.

Hope this helps

Comment: SO this is how code igniter sets up  it stores all the called view in a buffer  and displays them last  is there way to achieve what i have explained?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the random function. If you wanted to inject a function into your view, you could just use a helper file to store your function, then it can be called directly in the view.

Comment: i have edited my question. i am not really doing any specific i am trying to learn CI   while doing testing i noticed this behavior of CI  so i want to know why this happens

Comment: As I said if you follow the /system/core/Codeigniter.php you will see what functions/classes/methods get called in order.  Ill edit my answer to list how these are called in order to help you understand better.

Comment: Thank you so much philip is there any indepth guide,book or some video tutorial that describes this whole scenario and where i can learn from?